# fopen a file with only part of title in php

Tags: php, csv, fopen

So i am trying to use fopen to call a file from my server that gets auto dowloaded everyday with the same partial title the same every time but only want to get the file for today. for example if the file is file20160310.csv i can get it with `$file = fopen('file'. $today . '.csv', 'r') or die('cant open file');` where `$today = date("m-d-y");`
(but the file name is file20160310875647.csv and the digits after the date are random) is there a way to stip these numbers from the title when i do fopen ( i cannot change the file it is lock)

Solution

Solution--so both answers below worked but i used the answer from T0xicCode for the inclusion of .$today. in the answer and egg answer for the help with fgetcsv

> $list = glob('ShipToUsShipments'. $today . '*.csv');
>
> $filename = $list[0];
>
> $file = fopen($filename, 'r') or die('cant open file');
>
> fetcsv($file,1000,",");
>
> ($line = fgetcsv(fopen($file))) { echo $line[0]; }

Comment: Try `file20160310*.csv`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [glob()](http://php.net/glob) to return a list of files that match the `fileYYYYMMDD*` format:

```
$list = glob('file20160310*.csv');
$file = $list[0] // Assuming there'll only be one match for each day.
$file = fopen($file, 'r') or die('cant open file');
```

If there's more than one file each day, then you can:

```
$list = glob('file20160310*.csv');
foreach ($list AS $file) {
    fopen($file, 'r') or die('cant open file');
}
```

Comment: I tried this and i am getting this warningWarning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /chroot/

Comment: This is down to your use of [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv). In its simplest form, it should be `while($line = fgetcsv(fopen($file))) { echo $line[0]; }`  to display first field of each row. [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) wasn't in your question, so it's difficult to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: sorry i left that part out here is what i have now  `$list = glob('file'. $today . '*.csv');
$filename = $list[0];
$file = fopen($filename, 'r') or die('cant open file');
 
        
 fgetcsv($file,1000,",");
 //iterating through csv file inserting data into store_form table
 while (($data=fgetcsv($file,1000,","))!==FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` requires the exact name of the file. You will need to find the exact name of the file. You will be able to use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to figure out the complete name of the file:

```
$list = glob('file' . $today . '*.csv');
$filename = $list[0];
$file = fopen($filename, 'r') or die('cant open file');
```

`glob` returns an array, so you have to index into it. If multiple files match the given pattern, you'll have to figure out which one to use.